# what is another way to say " I have done task A task B and task C for free for this project"?

Tags: grammar, paraphrasing

I want another way to say:

> "I have done task A task B and task C for free for this project"

I wish to sound more professional.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is neither a writers workshop nor a proofreading service. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of acceptable topics here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro bono
In legal terms it means for public good, and etymologically too, but it means to something voluntarily and for free